# Institutional email for mathematical organization

Tags: email, affiliation

I'm a member of a mathematical organization which is not tied to any university, but rather has members from several different institutions (who are mathematicians). Furthermore, the organization even has its own journal that it publishes.

Currently, I am affiliated with a university, and this is the institutional email that I use. However, I was wondering if it was possible for the organization to create its own institutional email. For example, I would like to link my Google Scholar account or Arxiv account to this email.

What are some possible ways to implement this idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you asking about whether Google Scholar or arXiv would recognize it as an institutional domain? Because otherwise this question is not at all specific to academia; any organization or individual can set up their own email addresses, of course.

Comment: @Anyon Yes, this is what I was asking. More specifically, what needs to be done in order for it to be recognized as an institutional domain.

Comment: Recognized by whom? Journals? These days any email is accepted. You see Gmail addresses all the time for corresponding authors.

Comment: @cheer Perhaps in some areas, but not mine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the organization has a website, it must be hosted somewhere. They likely pay for shared hosting. Most shared hosting providers include free email addresses linked to the domain name. If not, they do for a small fee. When you use this address as author, the paper will be automatically linked to this address. Then you just have to link your Google scholar profile to this address (I don't like Google scholar, just mention it because it's what the OP asked.)

Comment: The "small fee" might be something like $5/user/month. If the org has hundreds of members, they might balk at paying this fee since members already have emails from their home institutions. For example, the Society for Neuroscience does not provide emails to its members.

Comment: @jerlich Fees like that are possible but it is equally possible and afaik more common that the generic hosting of a website for say $20/month already comes with 20 or 100 free email addresses. Depends on the provider, if you have an exceptionally greedy one it might be worth changing.

Comment: It often depends on storage. Emails that simply forward on to someplace else (gmail or ISP-provided email or personal domains, etc.) are often bundled practically unlimited with a domain (never truly "unlimited", but if it is 1,000 or 10,000 then it might as well be unlimited for most situations). But storage costs and POP/IMAP hosting costs, so typically there will be a limit on *hosted* email accounts either in terms on number of accounts or total storage (in GB) or both. But on top of all that, it is still a policy decision as to whether to give out lots of accounts or not.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, organizations can have their own email servers. ACM.org does, for example. It is also possible to contract out the service to a larger organization like Microsoft but still maintain an institutional domain: steppenwolf@mathgeeks.org, say. Money is needed, of course.